# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY but the json respone has already an object

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am learning retrofit 2 and got an error like this :

> W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 94 path $.riceField
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
> at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
> at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)

and here is the code

api

```
@GET(Server.riceFields+"/{id}")
Call<Product> showRiceFields(@Path("id") int id);
```

model

```
public class Product {

    private Status status;
    private RiceField riceField;

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public RiceField getRiceField() {
        return riceField;
    }

    public void setRiceField(RiceField riceField) {
        this.riceField = riceField;
    }


}
```

and

```
ProductsEndPoint.productsEndPoint().showRiceFields(id)
            .enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, Response<Product> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        RiceField riceField = response.body().getRiceField();
                        product = riceField;
                        setView(product);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

json respone

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "Succes",
        "description": "Data berhasil diambil"
    },
    "riceField": [
        {
            "id": 21,
            "title": "Nihil qui placeat tempora magnam aut omnis quae alias aliqua Molestiae culpa",
            "harga": 45,
            "luas": 20,
            "alamat": "Ratione cum et aliqu",
            "maps": "Quia aut ut dolores nisi hic necessitatibus asperiores odio dolores ut non voluptatum ipsum enim id",
            "deskripsi": "Voluptatum repellend",
            "sertifikasi": "sgb",
            "tipe": "jual",
            "created_at": "2021-06-08T08:11:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-08T08:11:00.000000Z",
            "user_id": 2,
            "vestige_id": 2,
            "irrigation_id": 3,
            "region_id": 3,
            "verification_id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

i have add List on the callback like this `<List<Product>>`
and the error turn to

> BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

so, what should i do?

thanks and sorry for my bad english

the solution : i should add List on model every array json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong model. according to your json output, your model must be the below classes

```
public class Output{

public Status status;
public List<RiceField> riceField;

}


public class RiceField {

public Integer id;
public String title;
public Integer harga;
public Integer luas;
public String alamat;
public String maps;
public String deskripsi;
public String sertifikasi;
public String tipe;
public String createdAt;
public String updatedAt;
public Integer userId;
public Integer vestigeId;
public Integer irrigationId;
public Integer regionId;
public Integer verificationId;

}


public class Status {

public Integer code;
public String message;
public String description;

}
```

for more information use this website :
[json to java class](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: thank you so much.

so i should add List on model every array respone