# Unable to parse Json data in Android Kotlin MVVM architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I am creating an application in which I am calling rest api and storing all the data in SQLite Room Database and then I am retrieving that data from Room Database and display in RecycleView

below is my view model

```
    class CompletedTaskSummaryViewModel(private val repository: CompletedTaskSummaryRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _completedTaskSummaryList = MutableLiveData<List<CompletedTaskSummaryReport>>()
    val completedTaskSummaryList: LiveData<List<CompletedTaskSummaryReport>> get() = _completedTaskSummaryList

    var completedTaskListener: CompletedTaskSummaryReportListener? = null

    fun getCompletedTaskSummaryReport() {
        completedTaskListener?.onStarted()

        Coroutines.main {
            try {
                val completedTaskSummaryRequest = CompletedTaskSummaryRequest(
                    frmdate = "2023-09-01",
                    todate = "2023-11-10"
                )

                val authResponse = repository.getCompletedTaskSummary(completedTaskSummaryRequest)

                authResponse.nestedData?.let { responseObject ->
                    val nestedList = responseObject.firstOrNull()?.data?.firstOrNull().orEmpty()
                    if (nestedList.isNotEmpty()) {
                        _completedTaskSummaryList.value = nestedList
                        repository.saveCompletedTaskSummaryList(nestedList)
                        completedTaskListener?.onSuccess(nestedList)
                    }
                    return@main
                }


            } catch (e: ApiExceptions) {
                completedTaskListener?.onFailure(e.message!!)
            } catch (e: NoInternetException) {
                completedTaskListener?.onFailure(e.message!!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

below is my data class which is holding data received from api

```
    data class CompletedTaskSummaryResponse<T>(
    val rId: Int,
    val nestedData: List<NestedData<T>>?,
    val eId: Int?,
    val eDesc: String?
)

data class NestedData<T>(
    val data: List<T>?
)
```

below is my repository

```
class CompletedTaskSummaryRepository(private val api: MyApi, private val db: AppDatabase) :
    SafeApiRequest() {

    suspend fun getCompletedTaskSummary(completedTaskSummaryRequest: CompletedTaskSummaryRequest): CompletedTaskSummaryResponse<List<CompletedTaskSummaryReport>> {
        return apiRequest { api.GetCompletedTaskSummaryReport(completedTaskSummaryRequest) }
    }

    suspend fun saveCompletedTaskSummaryList(completedTaskSummaryList: List<CompletedTaskSummaryReport>) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            db.getCompletedTaskReport().upsert(completedTaskSummaryList)
        }
    }

    fun getCompletedTaskSummaryReport() =
        db.getCompletedTaskReport().getCompletedTaskSummaryReport()
}
```

below function is in my MyApi interface

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json", "AuthenticationKey: 51b1d8b6-02d8-4fe7-af9e-a10d5a05d95c")
    @POST("api/JobManagement/getCompletedTaskSummaryReport")
    suspend fun GetCompletedTaskSummaryReport(
        @Body completedTaskSummaryRequest: CompletedTaskSummaryRequest
    ): Response<CompletedTaskSummaryResponse<List<CompletedTaskSummaryReport>>>
```

below is my SQLite Database Room entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "completedtasksummary")
data class CompletedTaskSummaryReport(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    var CompletedDate: String? = null,
    var TotalCompletedTask: Int? = null,
    var TotalTeam: Int? = null
)
```

Below is my dao

```
@Dao
interface CompletedTaskSummaryReportDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsert(user: List<CompletedTaskSummaryReport>){
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            // Call your non-suspending DAO method here
            val result = upsertNonSuspending(user)
            continuation.resume(result)
        }
    }

    //Non-suspending version of upsert
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun upsertNonSuspending(user: List<CompletedTaskSummaryReport>)

//    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
//    suspend fun upsert(completedTaskSummaryReport: CompletedTaskSummaryReport): Long
//
//    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
//    suspend fun upsertAll(completedTaskSummaryList: List<CompletedTaskSummaryReport>)

    @Query("Select * from completedtasksummary")
    fun getCompletedTaskSummaryReport(): LiveData<List<CompletedTaskSummaryReport>>
}
```

below is my api response

```
{
    "rId": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "CompletedDate": "13-Oct-2023",
                    "TotalCompletedTask": 1,
                    "TotalTeam": 1
                },
                
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

below is my safeApi abstract class

```
abstract class SafeApiRequest {

    suspend fun <T : Any> apiRequest(call: suspend () -> Response<T>): T {
        val response = call.invoke()

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            return response.body()!!
        } else {
            val errorBody = response.errorBody()?.string()
            val message = parseErrorMessage(errorBody)
            throw ApiExceptions(message)
        }
    }

    private fun parseErrorMessage(errorBody: String?): String {
        return if (!errorBody.isNullOrBlank()) {
            try {
                val jsonError = JSONObject(errorBody)
                jsonError.optString("message", "Unknown error")
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                "Error parsing JSON response"
            }
        } else {
            "Empty or null error response"
        }
    }
}
```

now I am not getting any error and when I am evaluating response.body() then I am getting value of rId = 0 but getting null in nestedData instead of data

Comment: this might help: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154917/retrofit-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077649/expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-at-line-1-column-2-little-edit) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67955557/expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-but-the-json-respone-has-already-an-ob) similarly there are so many answers you can check

Answer (score 0):

`Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY` simply means that some json actually starts with `[` and not with `{` and this is the case for the `data` field.

The top level `data` is an array but you are treating it as a single object. Changing

```
val data: NestedData<T>?,
```

to

```
val data: List<NestedData<T>>?,
```

might solve your problem

Comment: Thank you @Ivo for you respose. can you please suggest changes in view model according to above suggested changes

Answer (score 0):

Your api response contains two nested array objects under "data" key. NestedData rightfully has "data" field with a list of T. But the "data" field in CompletedTaskSummaryResponse should also have a "List" type, actually it has to be

```
val data: List<NestedData<T>>?
```

Also you need to create a data class holding "CompletedDate" and other necessary fields and use it instead of T.

Comment: Thank you @Anna Now I am getting Unresolved reference: data at val nestedList = responseObject.data in view model

Comment: could you share additional code in order to understand where might be a problem?

Comment: I have completely updated my code and not while evaluating respose.body() i am getting rId = 0 and null in nestedData instead of all the data.